# An attempt was made to get a data value of type 'java.sql.Blob' from a data value of type 'CHAR () FOR BIT DATA'

Tags: java, jdbc, derby

I'm trying to read from a Derby database in a generalized way and I want to retrieve UUID as byte array 16. Usually with binary types, I can use Blob and map this to a byte array. In Derby though, I get this exception: 'An attempt was made to get a data value of type 'java.sql.Blob' from a data value of type 'CHAR () FOR BIT DATA'.'

SCHEMA

```
CREATE TABLE Contacts(  ID CHAR(16) FOR BIT DATA NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY ... etc
```

This gives me java.sql.Types -2 (BINARY)

It fails when I use rs.getBlob :

```
 byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    Blob blob = rs.getBlob(column);
    try (InputStream in = blob.getBinaryStream()) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream((int) blob.length());
        for (int len; (len = in.read(buffer)) != -1; ) {
            bos.write(buffer, 0, len);
        }
        value = bos.toByteArray();
    }
```

But it does work if I use:

```
value = rs.getBytes(column)
```

Now I could just use rs.getBytes unless later I would also need a "real" Blob from Derby. How could I tell the difference? Or does Derby just always use getBytes?

Comment: `CHAR FOR BIT DATA` is not the same as `BLOB`. They are two different data types. And neither is the same as `CLOB`. Use the JDBC `BLOB` API for access to `BLOB` and `CLOB` columns, and not for access to columns of other data types. Is this your question?

Comment: @BryanPendleton It's fine. As long as I was able to tell the difference from the jdbc meta data. I can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `java.sql.Blob` for JDBC type `BINARY` is wrong from a strict JDBC API interpretation, no matter which driver you use. Using `getBytes` is always the appropriate method for this type (`getBinaryStream` should also work). See also the [JDBC 4.3 specification](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/mrel/jsr221/index3.html), appendix B, specifically table B-3, which defines the default Java type for JDBC type `BINARY` as `byte[]`, and B-5, which only defines a mapping from a `java.sql.Blob` to JDBC type `BLOB`, and B-6 which only defines support for `getBlob` for columns of JDBC type `BLOB`.

To be clear, JDBC type `BINARY` - usually - maps to/from the SQL type `BINARY` (Derby's equivalent is called `CHAR FOR BIT DATA`), which is a fixed-length byte string/array type. Whereas a SQL (and JDBC) `BLOB` is a type holding binary data of varying length (usually of unlimited length (or at least extremely large)) through a so-called locator object. `BLOB` data is generally stored off-row (the row only contains a pointer or id of the actual data), whereas `BINARY` (and `VARBINARY`) are usually stored inline. A `java.sql.Blob` is the Java representation of that locator object, providing an indirection to access the off-row data of the blob.

However, some drivers are more lenient, either for backwards compatibility with earlier versions of the driver, or for maximum portability (e.g. bridge implementation differences between different database systems). For example, some drivers may define their (SQL) `BLOB` types as JDBC `LONGVARBINARY` instead (which supports `getBytes` and `getBinaryStream`), but may then also define support for `getBlob` for cases where users assume *"I use a SQL `BLOB`, so I should use `getBlob`"*.

So, in short, if the column is identified as JDBC type `BINARY`, then use `getBytes` (or `getInputStream`, however if you want to get a UUID, which is always 16 bytes, then using `getBytes` makes more sense). If the row is identified as JDBC type `BLOB`, then use `getBlob` (though some drivers may also support `getBytes` and `getInputStream`, this is not specified in JDBC).

Comment: Thanks. Yeah I realized there's a java.sql.Types for Blob and for various Binary types.

Comment: @sproketboy Yes, JDBC type `BINARY` does not mean "any binary data type", it only covers the fixed-length binary data type which the SQL standard calls `BINARY` (there is also `VARBINARY` and `LONGVARBINARY` (though the SQL standard doesn't specify that type), and of course `BLOB`).